# How to include the table generated in CGRIDVIEW to a <DIV> in YII

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am using Gridview with which I display the records coming from the database in a tabular form,a  is formed which holds the records. The pagination is also enabled so that I can jump to any page.

Now, I have to add a seperate div inside of Cgridview so that i can add styling to the table.

How to do this?

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type' => 'bordered striped',
    'id' => 'cars_search_grid',   
    'dataProvider' => $model->search_cars(),
    'ajaxUpdate' => true, 
    'filter' => null, 
    'columns' => $selected_columns,
    'enablePagination' => true
));
```

The structure of generated output is like this --->

```
<div id="cars_search_grid" class="grid-view">
    <table class="items table table-bordered table-striped">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div>'This DIV holds the {Pager}'</div>
        <div>'This DIV holds the {Summary}'<div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And My Goal is to output something like this --->

```
<div id="cars_search_grid" class="grid-view">
    <div> //This is where i want to put a DIV 
        <table class="items table table-bordered table-striped">
    </div> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div>'This DIV holds the {Pager}'</div>
        <div>'This DIV holds the {Summary}'<div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not xhtml valid though.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes gets me to my goal

added 'template' to the Gridview and it worked

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type' => 'bordered striped',
    'id' => 'cars_search_grid',   
    'dataProvider' => $model->search_cars(),
    'ajaxUpdate' => true, 
    'filter' => null,
    'template'=>'<div style="overflow:auto;">{items}</div>{pager}{summary}',
    'columns' => $selected_columns,
    'enablePagination' => true
));
```

Answer (score 0):

To style the table, simply use the CSS selector

```
.grid-view table.items {
```

or more specifically to this grid-view only,

```
#cars_search_grid table.items {
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open the [official api page](http://yiiapi.com/CGridView), you will see that there are lots of css classes that you can set, if not the defaults will be set for you

[pagerCssClass](http://yiiapi.com/CBaseListView#pagerCssClass-detail)

[summaryCssClass](http://yiiapi.com/CBaseListView#summaryCssClass-detail)

[loadingCssClass](http://yiiapi.com/CBaseListView#loadingCssClass-detail)